# Casing removable from word embeddings?

Tags: nlp, word-embedding, fasttext

Many words have multiple vectors because they are used with multiple casings. It seems to be quite unusual, though, that a word's casing alters its meaning. Can I combine vectors such that there's only one vector per word?

I was thinking of using a weighted geometric midpoint. The weighting would be a simple linear transformation that depends on the different word frequencies. How could I show that the new vector is valid, or that it is a good representation? I'm sure there must be other approaches to this.

Comment: Please explain better.
Are you using pretrained models from FastText or instead are you training your model?

Comment: Are you sure that text case doesn't affect the meaning? Think about colors: lowecase they are just colors but when capitalized usually refer to people 
(last names like White) or institutions (Brown university).

Comment: I am using pretrained FastText vectors.

Comment: Text case does not affect meaning. It is a syntactical convention that varies by language and writing style. There are some exceptions, for example, if the word is an acronym.